# Display label from one form to another form

Tags: c#

I have one form in my software that is displaying the total value (it is a `label`), and I want to display the value of that `label` on another form.

Here is my code:

```
public void PresmetajTotal()
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        vkp += Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

         lblTotal.Text = vkp.ToString();
    }
}
```

And on the other form I created this:

```
 private void Change_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Prodazba prodaz = new Prodazba();
     label4.Text = prodaz.lblTotal.Text();
 }
```

The error i get is :
CS0122  'Prodazba.lblTotal' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: When do you set the value of the label on the Prodzaba form?

Answer (score 1):

Add a public property in `Prodazba` form that will return the value of the label.

```
public partial class Prodazba()
{
    public string Total { get { return lblTotal.Text; } }

    //....
}
```

Then access it like:

```
private void Change_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Prodazba prodaz = new Prodazba();
    label4.Text = prodaz.Total;
}
```

Comment: Can i see the constructor of the Prodazba class?

Answer (score 0):

Tw things:

1. You are creating an new form with `new Prodazba()`
2. Your label is private

The second one is easier to deal with. In the form editor, or your designer code, set the access level to `internal` or `public`.

For the first one, you could take several approaches depending on how the forms are created. If your first form loads the Prodazba, you could:

```
public partial class YourMainForm
{
    Prodazba prodaz;
```

then...

```
private void Change_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prodaz = new Prodazba();
    prodaz.Load += delegate {this.label4.Text = prodaz.Total};
    prodaz.Show();
}
```

If your label is internally accessable, you could run any event handler from it, like `prodaz.label4.TextChanged += ...`